# SSH with a user alias?

Tags: server, ssh, alias

**This question is not a duplicate. Please read it before you mark it as such.**

Is it possible to assign nicknames or aliases to users on a Linux sever and SSH into the server using the nicknames? I am thinking something along the lines of the aliases for various commands that get added to the `.bashrc` or the `.bash_aliases` file, e.g.:

```
alias grep='grep --color=auto'
```

For example, if there is a requirement (business rule) to set up users on the server with their full name, e.g., `john_smith` instead of just their first name (`john`) but we want to nickname `john_smith` `fruitloops` and we want John to be able to:

```
ssh john_smith@ip_address
```

as well as:

```
ssh fruitloops@ip_address
```

If it is possible, where would the mapping between a user and their nickname be set up? Would the user `fruitloops` also need to exists on the sever?

**This question is about setting up an alias for a user, not a host**.

Comment: With a host alias you could do `ssh fruitloop`

Comment: My question is about setting up an alias for a user, not the host. `fruitloops` refers to the user `john_smith`, not the IP address.

Comment: That's what a `User    fruitloop` line would be for. You can add several entries in one config file.

Comment: I believe these are not the same questions ... +1 to question ;)

Comment: Sorry for my misunderstanding - a SSH host alias would have to be set up on the **client** but what you need is a solution that was set up on the **server**. Retracted my close vote.

Comment: I think this is possible with some PAM trickery (if you're using PAM that is).

I may be able to find some old code along these lines (if I do I'll post as an answer).

Comment: I don't really understand your real goal - you want to be able to access a remote account by not using the real (remote) account name ?

Comment: @guntbert, the requirement is to assign accounts to users on the remove using their full names e.g., `john_adam_smith_brown` but the users don't want to have to type that in everytime they want to SSH into the remote. They want to type something much shorter, like a nickname they chose for themselves or just their first name. So `john_adam_smith_brown` would like to SSH in as `jon`.

Comment: personally i found it sufficient to do `alias sshfoo='ssh hanshenrik@foo.com'`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Each user in linux has only one name and that is his only name. you can create aliases for commands not for users.

But you can create a second user with the same UID, home directory and password that would do the trick for you.

Comment: So my `/etc/passwd` entries corresponding to these users would look like: `john_smith:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/john_smith:/bin/bash` and
`fruitloops:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/john_smith:/bin/bash` ?

Comment: I tried 3 different approaches **after** adding user `john_smith` with `UID = 1001`. **1)** `adduser --home /home/john_smith --uid 1001 fruitloops`, this did not work (`adduser` failed because userid was taken) **2)** `useradd --home /home/john_smith --non-unique --uid 1001 fruitloops`, this did work but lead to some behaviour that wasn't desirable **3)** Finally I added the line `fruitloops:x:1001:1001:,,,:/home/john_smith:/bin/bash` directly to the `/etc/passwd` file and this was closest to what I was after. I SSH into `ip_address` as `fruitloops` and land in `/home/john_smith` upon arrival.

Comment: I'm going to quibble with your wording here.  In your scenario, you've created one user (1001) with two different login names. You haven't done it here, but there's no reason the two names can't have different home directories and login shells.  Log in as "fruitloops" and create a file.  Now check the directory and you'll see that john_smith is shown as the file's owner, because that's the first name found in /etc/passwd for uid 1001.  We can argue about whether john_smith is the name and fruitloops is an alias, or john_smith is the primary name and fruitloops secondary, but that's semantic.

Comment: "you can create a second user with the same UID, home directory and password" – that sounds like a terrible hack that's not guaranteed to work across different POSIX-compliant implementations. POSIX requires that the relationship between user names and user IDs be bidirectionally distinct.

Comment: @dw8547 Can you explain a bit more about the undesirable behavior from the useradd command?

Comment: @MontyHarder, when the user arrives at the host, we want the default shell to be bash. When testing this out with approach 2) above *without any additional changes to the configuration files for the user*, when we arrive at the host, we land in the POSIX shell. In this shell, the prompt looks like `$` so the user doesn't see the helpful information that the bash shell displays at the prompt, i.e., `user_name@host_name:current_directory$`.

Comment: @MontyHarder, yes, if the user logs in as `fruitloops` and say creates a file, the file owner and author is showing up as `john_smith`. That is in fact what we want. We only want to be able to SSH in with what is supposed to be a shorter alias. In the example I made up `fruitloops` isn't really that much shorter but we want to come up with a solution that will allow `john_adam_smith_brown` to log in as `jon` and `daniel_john_smith_white` to log in as `dan`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried this but another option besides the two users mapped to a single UID (which IMO seems dangerous but this option is probably equally dangerous) is to have a single user serve as a redirector based on SSH key. This is how source control repositories that use SSH typically work.

Lets call the user `me`. Everyone will use this alias.

```
ssh me@ip_address
```

Now the user `me` has all of users public keys in their `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.

```
command="sudo -i -u user-mapped-to-key" ssh-rsa key
```

You will need to make the user `me` have the ability to sudo as the other users and you will need to manage `me` authorized keys file.

Anyway I haven't tested this but in theory something like this should work.